# dosen't run three.js file on twig file

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

Does any body know, how can run the `three.js` on the twig file?
I can't see the cube in twig file.

`a.html:`

```
  var angularSpeed = 0.2; 
  var lastTime = 0;

  // this function is executed on each animation frame
  function animate(){
    // update
    var time = (new Date()).getTime();
    var timeDiff = time - lastTime;
    var angleChange = angularSpeed * timeDiff * 2 * Math.PI / 1000;
    cube.rotation.y += angleChange;
    lastTime = time;

    // render
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    // request new frame
    requestAnimationFrame(function(){
        animate();
    });
  }

  // renderer
  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  // camera
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
  camera.position.z = 500;

  // scene
  var scene = new THREE.Scene();

  // cube
  var cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(50, 50, 50), new   THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());
  cube.overdraw = true;
  scene.add(cube);

  // start animation
  animate();
```

And I want it add into the my twig file:

```
{% include 'welcome/a.html' %}
```

Comment: Do you wrap your js in <script> tag ?

Comment: any error message or other infos that could help ?

Comment: `no.i have not any error at all`

Comment: `just can't see the cube`